# How can I make such an paper swipe animation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

[image]

I want to make an animation like that.There will be a button in the bottomside of this paper.When user tap this button.It should animate like that.How can I do it?

I tried to make it with Pageview ,but I could not get the same animation in this gif.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flip_widget. Try this package

Comment: Thanks Ramji I tried ,but I could not get hte same thing